# Laravel pass object to method in model

Tags: php, laravel

In my User model I can do:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
  $message = (new UserForgotPassword($this->email, $this->name, $token));
}
```

but how can I pass the full `User` object?

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
  $message = (new UserForgotPassword($user, $token));
}
```

Using `$user` doesn't work, while it does work in:

```
protected static function booted()
{
  static::creating(function ($user) {
    $user->uuid = Str::uuid();
  });
}
```

Comment: just use this instead,
  $message = (new UserForgotPassword($this, $token));

Comment: Didn't know I could do that!

Comment: yea, u could, let me know if you face any prob :))

Comment: @Abdel-azizhassan if you post that as an answer I can accept it :-)

Comment: Okay, I will thanks :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this instead,

```
$message = (new UserForgotPassword($this, $token));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this` to have access to the User instance inside the User model (in a non-static method).

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
  $message = (new UserForgotPassword($this, $token));
}
```

Note: If your method was a static method, you would use `static` (or `self`) instead of `$this`.

Also, in the example you gave, `$user` is not actually a variable in the `booted` method. It is rather a parameter of the closure (the anonymous function) passed to the `created` method.